# Raw sockets in C vs SOCK_DGRAM

Tags: c, sockets, udp

From my understanding, raw sockets give you a lot of work as compared to SOCK_DGRAM, since you need to create your own packets, handle buffering and all of that...

BUT, in the context of a program that I'am developing for a system with low CPU processing and trying to achieve the network maximum bandwidth, I was wondering if - using RAW sockets and bypassing some of the kernel processing, avoid checksum, etc - I could save some overhead and potentially , as a result get some better throughput results.

Or maybe this could be just a waste of time and the difference would be negligible.

Comment: The network itself is the bottleneck, the overhead of the socket code is not likely to make a significant difference.

Comment: UDP is a very simple protocol, it's unlikely there will be much difference between the kernel's creation of the UDP header and doing it yourself with a raw socket. And it has had decades of optimization.

Comment: On most platforms, RAW sockets require admin rights to use them.  Which platform(s) are you targeting? On windows, for instance, you can use [RIO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh997032(v=ws.11)) to achieve higher socket performance without relying on RAW/admin access.

Comment: The network is prepared for 10 Gb/s. My system is Linux and so far I have managed to get 6.8/Gbs upload with batch processing and multi threading. I want to achieve 8/Gbs using UDP sockets.

Download is not an issue, I get the speeds I want. Upload is the problem.